# Sequence not overflowing

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I am trying to figure out how a table insert behaves when the corresponding sequence overflows in Postgres. To test this, I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id SERIAL
);
```

This created a corresponding sequence

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('t1', 'id');
 pg_get_serial_sequence
------------------------
 public.t1_id_seq
(1 row)
```

I edited the sequence manually and set a max value

```
alter sequence t1_id_seq MAXVALUE 5;
```

At this point, I expected I won't be able to insert to the table once the sequence reaches it's maximum value. But I saw that I can still insert to the table.

```
insert into t1 select * from generate_series(10,100);
INSERT 0 91
```

And the sequence nextval is set to 1

```
select * from nextval('t1_id_seq');
 nextval
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

Shouldn't table insert fail when the sequence overflows? Why is the sequence not overflowing in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your INSERT isn't using the sequence, but the values that are returned by `generate_series()`. So the sequence is never advanced and thus it doesn't throw an error during the insert.

If you don't provide a value for the `id` column or use `default`, then you'd get the expected error:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id SERIAL
);

alter sequence t1_id_seq MAXVALUE 5;

-- this advances the sequence by 5 values
insert into t1
values (default),(default),(default),(default),(default);

-- this will fail
insert into t1
values (default);
```

The fact that you can bypass the sequence is precisely the reason, why the `serial` pseudo-type is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favor of the standard compliant `identity` columns